# declarativeNetRequest rule ignored for mixed-content requests

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I'm trying to avoid blocking mixed-content by upgrading requests scheme to `https` using the `declarativeNetRequest` API.

With the following basic rule:

```
{
    condition: {
        excludedResourceTypes:['ping']
    },
    action: {
        type:'upgradeScheme'
    }
}
```

It seems to work only for `main_frame` requests while insecure `sub_frame` requests are being blocked immediately without attempt to upgrade.

> Mixed Content: The page at https://localhost.com was loaded over
> HTTPS, but requested an insecure script http://localhost.com/script.js -
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You can report it on https://crbug.com.